# Python iterating on JSON objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code

```
images = {
    "alpine": [
        {
            "tag": "3.11",
            "creation_date": "2020-01-18T01:19:37.187497623Z"
        }
    ]
}

for image in images:
    print(image)
    for tag in image:
        print(tag)
```

Here's the output

```
alpine
a
l
p
i
n
e
```

here's what i want to happen

```
print(tag['tag'])
3.11

print(tag['creation_date'])
2020-01-18T01:19:37.187497623Z
```

Comment: You probably want to iterate over `images["alpine"]`, not `images`. If you want to go through all the keys and values in the dictionary use `items` method or `values` for values only. For example
```python
for image in images["alpine"]:
    for value in image.values():
        print(value) 
```

Comment: have you tried images.items()

Comment: This is no a "json object". JSON is a text-based serialization format. You are working with a python `dict` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
>>> for key in images.keys():
...     for d in images[key]:
...         print(d['tag'], d['creation_date'])
... 
3.11 2020-01-18T01:19:37.187497623Z
```